# function unable to access immediate state change using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to learn how to use Hooks

I am rendering a list of an array remove the first element onclick the state is getting updated in that handleclick function but it not rendering

````
export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [arry, setArry] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  const _log = () => {
    let ar = arry;
    ar.shift();
    setArry(ar);
    console.log(arry, "log");
  };

  const renderlist = () => {
    console.log(arry, "--");
    if (arry.length > 1) {
      return arry.map((a) => <li>{a}</li>);
    }
  }; //

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={_log}>shift</button>
      {renderlist()}
    </div>
  );
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**React compares objects and arrays by reference instead of by value**. This means that what React is checking is the position of memory in which your array is allocated, and not the actual content of your array. As long as that reference remains the same, React won't detect any changes done inside of your array.

```
let ar = arry;
ar.shift();
setArry(ar);
```

Your `ar` variable here is nothing but a pointer to the current `arry` variable. When you do `setArry(ar)`, what you're doing is assign that same pointer again to your `arry` value. This is the reason why it's not rendering: **since the reference to the array is still the same, React is not aware of the changes you've made**.

In order to fix this, you need to create a new array instance with the changes and pass it to `setArry`.

```
setArry([...ar]);
```

Here we're using detructuring to create a copy of your current `ar` array. Since this copy is a completely different element, it has a different reference. Because of that, calling `setArry` with this new item will cause your component to re-render with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass different value (array) to the `setArry`. Because `useState` is optimised to not change value if `newValue === currValue`.

You pass same array because you mutate it which is anti-pattern (as you see in action) in React.

```js
  const _log = () => {
    const [_, ...ar] = arry;
    setArry(ar);
    // or setArry(([_, ...ar]) => ar);
    console.log(arry, "log");
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a copy of the array before you make a change otherwise you'll still be referencing the original array.

```
let ar = [...arry];
```

And change your condition slightly:

```
if (arry.length > 0) {
```

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

function Example() {

  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [arry, setArry] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

  const _log = () => {
    let ar = [...arry];
    ar.shift();
    setArry(ar);
    // console.log(arry, "log");
  };

  const renderlist = () => {
    // console.log(arry, "--");
    if (arry.length > 0) {
      return arry.map((a) => <li>{a}</li>);
    }
  }; //

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={_log}>shift</button>
      {renderlist()}
    </div>
  );

};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```